# Telegram Bot custom keyboard JAVA

Tags: java, keyboard, telegram

I have my custom keyboard like calculator (1,2,3..0). When i click the digit button it sends the message< but i want to send message only when i typed full digit.
Example: i want to send 1000, but it sends 1, then 0, then 0..
my keyboard:

```
ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyBoardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
    List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
    KeyboardRow row = new KeyboardRow();
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      row.add(Integer.valueOf(i).toString());
      if (i % 3 == 0) {
        keyboard.add(row);
        row = new KeyboardRow();
      }
    }
    row.add("0");
    keyboard.add(row);
    keyBoardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    keyBoardMarkup.setResizeKeyboard(true);
```

Comment: You have to log it yourself :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the normal keyboard buttons like this. When you press them, they sends the value as a new message.

You can use [inline keyboards](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) for this type of cases. Record all button clicks and edit the message which contains your inline keyboard. It'll have a better ui also, in this way.

You need to use these two things:

1. editMessageText: Edit the message when user clicks a button. For example, when user touched to the button 1, then edit the message which contains your buttons. Then save the last edited version of this message. When user presses another button, do the same thing for this button to. In this case, your buttons and message will work like a program without sending new messages.
2. InlineKeyboardMarkup: To do the same thing explained in the section 1., use this markup. You'll add the inline keyboard buttons to this markup. They're working like normal KeyboardButtons.